# Spring boot exception at the time of run application

Tags: spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am getting below exception when tried to start application. I have added project as dependency in another maven project. I am new in spring boot pls help me.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.mre.utility</groupId>
            <artifactId>mre-utility</artifactId>
            <version>1703.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Above is spring dependency added in main project.

```
 org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at com.att.mre.femtocell.Application.main(Application.java:49) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:117) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:537) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'httpPutFormContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:234) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:182) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:177) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:241) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:228) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:558) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar:2.8.6]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:474) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar:2.8.6]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:588) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:57) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:61) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:63) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.java:29) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.httpPutFormContentFilter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:138) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$95367f4f.CGLIB$httpPutFormContentFilter$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$95367f4f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cf44771e.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$95367f4f.httpPutFormContentFilter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: the dependency required is not found at class path. Maven creates two files when you build your project, one slim jar and another fat jar. Fat jar is self sufficient but slim jar needs libraries to be present with proper classpath. Please tell more about what you are doing, how you are trying to run your application

Comment: Thank you for immediate reply. I have one main project and I am adding another project as dependency after that my code is compile but not able to run application. When tried to run application it throw the above exception.

Comment: you're welcome. so let's verify, does your class path includes the jackson databind jar?